# Unix bash cutting and grep

Tags: bash, unix, grep, cut

I have a text file called db.txt.
Some sample lines from the file goes as such:

> Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone:J.K. Rowling:21.95:100:200
>
> Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets:J.K. Rowling:21.95:150:300
>
> Lord of the Rings, The Fellowship of the Ring:J.R.R. Tolkien:32.00:500:500
>
> A Game of Thrones:George R.R. Martin:44.50:300:250

Then in my script, I have the following lines:

```
echo "Enter title:"
read TITLE

cut -d ":" -f 1 db.txt | grep -iw "$TITLE" | while read LINE
do
    STRING="`echo $LINE | cut -d ":" -f 1`,"
    STRING="$STRING `echo $LINE | cut -d ":" -f 2`, "
    STRING=" \$$STRING`echo $LINE | cut -d ":" -f 3`,"
    STRING=" $STRING`echo $LINE | cut -d ":" -f 4`,"
    STRING=" $STRING`echo $LINE | cut -d ":" -f 5`"
done
```

Is there a way to grep a specific field from cut and then pass in the full line into the while loop?

For example, if I entered "Harry Potter",
it should display:

> Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, J.K. Rowling, $21.95, 100, 200
>
> Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, J.K. Rowling, $21.95, 150, 300

Comment: A loop on lines in shell is anormal. All commands (grep, sed, cut, etc...) use already a loop on lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this without `cut`, and without `grep` if you're ok with bash's regular expression matching (or can use shell pattern matching instead).

The idea would be to read the file line by line, then split the line into an array.
Once you've got that, do the comparisons and output you want.

Here's a demo of the technique:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Title:"
read title

# shopt -s nocasematch           # if you want case-insensitive matching

while read line ; do             # this read takes data from input.txt, see
                                 # end of loop
        IFS=: read -a parts <<< "$line"  # this splits the line on ":" into
                                         # an array called parts

        if [[ ${parts[0]} =~ $title ]] ; then  # regex matching
                printf "%s -- %s\n" "${parts[1]}" "${parts[2]}"
        fi
done < input.txt
```

Comment: One more thing I want to add, how do you check for case-insensitivity and how do I go about printing out the numbers at the back? I tried %d but the numbers end up as a zero.

Comment: Uncomment the `shopt` line in the post to get case-insensitive matching. Try `$%.02f` for the dollar amount, `%d` for whole numbers works just fine with the data you provided.

Comment: grep "Harry Potter" db.txt should do it !

Comment: @ArifBurhan: wouldn't produce the desired output, and wouldn't match on the title only

Answer (score 4):

The next step up from `grep` and `cut` is `awk`. Unless you must do this using `bash` (is this homework?), then `awk` would make things considerably easier:

```
awk -F: '/harry potter/ { sub(/^/,"$",$(NF-2)); print }' IGNORECASE=1 OFS=", " db.txt
```

Test input:

```
Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone:J.K. Rowling:21.95:100:200
Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets:J.K. Rowling:21.95:150:300
Lord of the Rings, The Fellowship of the Ring:J.R.R. Tolkien:32.00:500:500
A Game of Thrones:George R.R. Martin:44.50:300:250
```

Test output:

```
Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, J.K. Rowling, $21.95, 100, 200
Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, J.K. Rowling, $21.95, 150, 300
```

Answer (score 3):

```
read -p "Enter title: " TITLE
while IFS=: read title author price x y; do
    if [[ ${title,,} == *${TITLE,,}* ]]; then
        printf "%s, %s, $%s, %s, %s\n" "$title" "$author" "$price" "$x" "$y"
    fi
done < db.txt
```

The test in the if command does a simple glob-match but case insensitively, so it will match if the user enters "potter".

Or, use sed to change the separators:

```
read -p "Enter title: " TITLE
sed '/'"$TITLE"'/I!d; s/:/, /g' db.txt
```

which means delete all lines that do not match the TITLE, then transform the separator.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method of doing this is to look over the grep results

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter title: " TITLE

FILENAME="db.txt"
IFS=$'\n'
for LINE in `grep -iw  "Harry Potter" "$FILENAME"`; do
    echo $LINE | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ":" } ; { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }'
done
```

The IFS change changes the delimiter to a new line rather than a space and the FS in the awk command changes the delimiter to the : to allow access to the fields

Answer (score 2):

I know you didn't specify it, but `awk` is probably the best tool to use for this task. It combines cut, sed, and grep into one convenient and easy to use tool. Well, convenient tool...

To understand `awk`, you have to understand a few things:

- Awk is a programming language. It has built in logic and variables.
- Awk assumes a read loop reading each and every line.
- Awk programs must be surrounded by curly braces.
- Not only curly braces, but Awk parsing variables start with dollar signs. Therefore, you need to put your Awk programs surrounded by single quotes to keep the shell out of it.
- Awk automatically parses each line based upon the *field separator*. The default field separator is a while space, but you can change that via the `-f` parameter.
- Each *field* gets a special variable. THe first field is `$1`, the next field is `$2`, etc. The entire line is `$0`.

Here's your Awk statement:

```
awk -F: '{
    title =  $1
    author = $2
    price  = $3
    pages_read_until_i_got_bored=$4
    pages = $5
    print "I read " pages_read_until_i_gob_bored "pages out of " $pages " pages of " $title " by " $author "."
}' $file
```

Of course, the whole thing could be a single line too:

```
 awk -F: '{ print "I read " $4 " pages " out of " $5 " of " $1 " by " $2 "." }' $file
```

Just wanted to emphasize the *programability* of Awk and how it can be used to do this type of parsing.

If your question is how to enter this information and put it into environment variables, [Glenn Jackman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14237481/368630) answer is the best.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `sed` this would be a solution

```
  read -p "Enter title: " TITLE
  sed -n -e 's/^\([^:]\+:\)\{2\}/\0$/' -e 's/:/, /g' -e "/^$TITLE/Ip" db.txt
```

Short explanation what it does

```
 -n tells sed not to print any lines
 -e 's/^\([^:]\+:\)\{2\}/\0$/' matches for the 2nd : and adds a $ after it
 -e 's/:/, /g' replaces all : with , and a following whitespace
 -e "/^$TITLE/Ip" tells sed to print all lines which start with $TITLE (that's the p) and I tells sed to match case-insensitive
```